# Google Glass CardBuilder.showStackIndicator() not found

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to use the [CardBuilder.showStackIndicator(boolean)](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardBuilder#showStackIndicator(boolean)) method, which was introduced in version XE22, but Android Studio tells me that the method can not be found.
I have the latest version installed from the SDK Manager and the latest software version installed on my Glass device. Is there something else that needs to be done to use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method should be in revision 11 of the GDK: make sure you've updated your add-on and refreshed your IDE.

If it doesn't show up in your IDE, try compiling anyway to make sure it's not a sync issue between autocomplete/autocompile and your SDK.

Comment: I had the revision 11 installed, and tryied to compile the project, but it didn't work. For some reason, now it does. Thank your!